# RadioGroup Right Aligned in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a textview on the left side and RadioGroup on the right side.  Before I put my buttons in a radio group I had the buttons on the right side of the screen.  What I am doing wrong after putting it in a RadioGroup?

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" >

  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/hair"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

             <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/Yes" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:text="@string/No" />



            </RadioGroup>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the "align" parameters that you have set on the buttons individually (like `layout_alignParentRight`) are no longer valid because the buttons are inside of a `RadioGroup`, which is a subclass of `LinearLayout`.  In order to right-align the group as a whole, you need to add the proper parameters to the `RadioGroup` itself.

Also, you may want the `RadioGroup` width to `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent`.  Otherwise any horizontal layout alignments you do will likely not be visible with the container trying to fill up all available space.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

you can also add this to your `RadioGroup` and it will work fine aswell!

```
android:gravity="center|left"
```